# Ampscript Triggered Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a simple solution for firing multiple triggered sends at once? I've successfully fired one based on a form, but i'm needing to send another form that lets a internal person know that said person got a email.(This person will be the same each time.) 
My initial thoughts were just to copy the code again below with different parameters but I wanted to know if there was a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same email, you can just add multiple subscribers in the code.  Or you can have SFMC support enable the [CC/BCC feature](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/) on the Triggered Send Definition, which is configurable in the interface.

This post may be helpful: [Sending a triggered send to multiple To/CC/BCC recipients via the API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/sending-a-triggered-send-to-multiple-to-cc-bcc-recipients-via-the-api).

Comment: I thought of this as well, although I realized we want this internal person to get a separate email. What I ended up doing was creating a email that has logic in it to see if anyone was added to the DE i'm putting the data to. If there was an update the email will be send daily via Automation Studio, if not it will raise and error and not send. Thanks for the help!