# CC Email Address on Email (ExactTarget)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

How can we specify the CC email address in the Triggered send definition? I know this is possible if we create the email definition using code.

But is it possible mention that on the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cc/bcc functionality is - or should be - available in the front-end when you create the Triggered Send Definition.

[image: Triggered Send Definition in Email Studio]

If you should not see the cc/bbc function yourself in your account, you should drop the Marketing Cloud Support team a quick note asking them to enable this in your account.

Comment: Chris is correct - you can also submit it as part of the API call as well if you your source application to control it
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/sending-a-triggered-send-to-multiple-to-cc-bcc-recipients-via-the-api