# Is it possible to include all DE registers in the CC/BCC functionality of an email in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

Someone enters a journey and an email is fired to that person. However I would like all registers in a DE to receive that email. Is it possible to include them inside the CC/BCC functionality?

Comment: What would be the use case for this? I am not quite certain what you are trying to accomplish by adding everyone on a CC/BCC?

Comment: I believe this is also covered in one of the answers on this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/sending-a-triggered-send-to-multiple-to-cc-bcc-recipients-via-the-api/58650#58650

Comment: As a note, I believe each of the CC/BCC on the email will still count as an individual send in SFMC, so if you are looking for a way to limit costs on sends - this is not the way. There are other 'gotchas' as well involved that would need to be considered too. (e.g. one person clicks the unsub link then no one will get the email again, only 1 reference for clicks/opens, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a column called CC(or something that makes sense to you) to your DE with as a default value for that field the emailaddress you want to CC/BCC, you can use a personalization string to add this to the CC/BCC field.

It's not out of the box but it does the trick.